# Meaning of -化 in context

Tags: words

I don't understand what the `-化` suffix in the following sentence means for a word like `カリスマ`, or why fearing it can lead to early retirement. Can anyone shine some light?

> 52歳の若さではあったが、カリスマ化を恐れて早々に身を引き、...

Comment: "Charisma" has some connotations of influencing/leading lots of people, so it might mean "I was 52 years young, but I was still concerned about going on the road to charismatification (and the responsibilities it would entail) and promptly retired..." (If "charismatification" isn't a word it should be BTW :P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's examine 化 and some compound words it forms:

> - 化(suffix) - action of making something
> - 悪化する - worsen, deteriorate. Lit: to make worse  
>     Corresponding noun (without する) : deterioration
> - 一体化する - unify, integrate. Lit: to make into one body 
>     Corresponding nouns: unification, integration
> - 一般化する - generalise. Lit: to make general/ordinary 
>     Corresponding nouns: generalisation, popularisation

Now for カリスマ化する, the literal meaning would roughly be "to make charismatic", and its corresponding noun would be as glacier puts it "charismatification". Not a real word but it's supposed to mean "the process of being made charismatic".

For the translation of the whole excerpt I think glacier has done a pretty good job in the question comment.

Comment: Now this is the kind of flexibility that a hacker appreciates in a language!